# Luau undefined reference to luau_compile

Tags: linker, luau

Im trying to link a custom built luau into my game, I built luau with this:
mkdir  build && cd build
cmake ..
make

after that I got following files:

- libLuau.VM.a
- libLuau.Compiler.a
- libLuau.CodeGen.a
- libLuau.Ast.a
- libLuau.Analysis.a

next step has been done was:

```
game = another game
engine_files = src/engine.c src/error/error_handler.cpp src/renderer/opengl.cpp
imgui_files = src/renderer/ui/imgui/*.cpp 
luau = -Llibs/luau/ -l:libLuau.Ast.a -l:libLuau.Analysis.a -l:libisocline.a -l:libLuau.CodeGen.a -l:libLuau.Compiler.a -l:libLuau.VM.a
build:
    g++ src/scripting/luau_integration.cpp $(engine_files) -std=c++17 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,'\$\$ORIGIN' glad.c -lm -lglfw3 -lGL -lwebp -lXrandr -lXinerama -lX11 -ldl -pthread -o bin/$(game) -L./ -l:imgui.so $(luau)
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./ && cd bin && ./confidental name removed
```

luau_integration.hpp:

```
/* You are granted license to view these files, modify them, study them they are not under cc by sa though*/
namespace Scripting{
    class Lua{
        public:
            static void Integrate();
    };
}
```

lua_integration.cpp

```
// public domain
// This loads game scripts
#include "../../libs/luau/include/Compiler.h"
#include "../../libs/luau/include/BytecodeBuilder.h"
#include "../../libs/luau/include/StringUtils.h"
#include "luau_integration.hpp"
#include "../../libs/luau/include/lua.h"
#include "../../libs/luau/include/luacode.h"
#include "../../libs/luau/include/lualib.h"
#include "../../libs/luau/include/StringUtils.h"
#include "../../libs/luau/include/BytecodeBuilder.h"



struct lua_CompileOptions options;

void Scripting::Lua::Integrate () {
    size_t binarySize;
    luau_compile("print(\"e\")", 11, &options, &binarySize);
}
```

luau files has been modified due directory difference,

Issue:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc8XT3MW.o: in function `Scripting::Lua::Integrate()':
luau_integration.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `luau_compile(char const*, unsigned long, lua_CompileOptions*, unsigned long*)'
```

Linker spits out this error no matter what I have tried, I can't find anything about installation prodecure of luau but im guessing it is similar to lua considering lack of documentation in the project everything is being done by trial and error and reading obscure comments in luau's source code.

What have I done possibly wrong?

Also please note that files are in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Using clang++ 13.x and g++ 12.x in Ubuntu 22.04, I follow the steps:

1. `git clone git@github.com/Roblox/luau.git`
2. `cd luau && mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make -j2`
3. I make a main.cpp file in the build directory:

```cpp
#include "../Compiler/include/luacode.h"


struct lua_CompileOptions options;

int main(void) {
    size_t binarySize;
    luau_compile("print(\"e\")", 11, &options, &binarySize);
    return 0;
}
```

4. I compile: `clang++ main.cpp libLuau.Compiler.a libLuau.Ast.a`
5. If I use the alternate form, it still works: `clang++ main.cpp -L. -l:libLuau.Compiler.a -l:libLuau.Ast.a`

I don't get any compile or link warnings/errors, and the program runs and terminates correctly. I'm guessing the `-l:` parts of your commandline aren't quite correct for linking static libraries, the .a files in your library path are empty or incorrectly built, or there is something missing from your reduced example.